# .NET changing crossorigin/> to crossorigin=""/>

Tags: c#, .net, preconnect

I'm trying to preconnect to resources on my .aspx page.

My code:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://vars.hotjar.com" crossorigin/>
```

Which .NET turns into

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://vars.hotjar.com" crossorigin=""/>
```

I've upgraded to VS2019, I'm pretty sure on past projects I've never had this problem so it may be a VS issue. Does anyone know how to bypass this change?

Thanks

Comment: The two expressions [are identical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes). There's no problem

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to bypass it? VS2019 is just correcting your typo to correct syntax

From term of functionality there is no difference.

Comment: Because crossorigin="" isn't correct syntax, I don't think? No browser recommends crossorigin="".

Comment: If you do not use that key, why you want to specify it?

Comment: @GerryHodson on the contrary, [crossorigin needs a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes). Omitting the value is the same as passing `""`

Comment: I've never added a value, check here: https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/